# Organization of the QT Code

Tags: c++, qt, code-organization

I am writing an application of middle size. I will have many gui components and many classes. However, it is difficult for me to organize the code, to separate the logic, ... For example, let say that I press one button that creates an object of a class and perform a computation on that object. After exiting the slot function of the button, this local object is destroyed. What if I need it in another function later? Defining everything as a global variable in the header file is not a good thing for me. So I was thinking of a static class that contains somehow pointers to all the objects I will need later. Does anybody has a better idea?

Comment: Do you mean `QObject` instances when you say "object"? These are usually constructed with `new` and thus are not destroyed automatically except when explicitly `delete`d or when the `QObject::parent()` is destroyed. So you usually do your book-keeping on the `QObject` level: hold references to children objects, and traverse the object hierarchy to access objects at any time.

Comment: No, I meant just an object of a custom class. Let say I am creating a local object of a Class A. Once exiting the function, this object is destroyed. So you need to keep him somewhere. In a Gui application everything is distributed and depending on events... I am searching for the best solution to organize my code. And I want to avoid to have only one class (my main class) where I store everything

Answer (score 2):

How to manage objects inside an application is always a tricky
question. Qt goes down a very object-oriented route and uses reference
semantics implemented through pointer for nearly everything. To
prevent tedious manual memory management Qt organizes everything into
[Object Trees](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/objecttrees.html). This
is augmented by Qt own
[object model](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/object.html) that adds
some dynamic capabilities.

If you want to go down that route, stick to everything Qt provides. It
is much more similar to Java than the usual C++ approach and might be
more comforting for beginners and maybe suits your application
domain. It tightly ties your code to Qt and will make it hard to
separate from it.

One other approach means to simply forgo all Qt stuff and work out the
core logic of your application. Develop it in pure C++ and than have a
thin layer that ties this logic into your Qt application through
signals and slots. In such an approach you would opt to use more
value-semantics.

For your concrete example of creating an algorithm and keeping it
around. The Qt approach:

```
class MyAlgo : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    MyAlgo(QObject* o) : QObject(o) { }

    virtual compute();
};

// use it in a mainwindow slot

void MainWindow::executeAlgorithm(const QString& name) {
   MyAlgo* algo = this->findChild<MyAlgo*>(name);
   if(!algo) {
     // not found, create
     algo = new MyAlgo(this); // make mainwindow the parent of this algo
     algo->setName(name); // QObject name property
   }

   algo->compute();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the QT approach, but I am searching for a general one in C++. For example I heard that the Singleton Pattern would be good enough to have thing global. However, there are disadvantages...  But at this point I thing I need to use it, because how otherwise can you keep your stuff stored? In OOP you have objects with their states and either you somehow do a distributed system in which objects communicate with each other (but I do not know exactly how I could achieve this) or you keep thing central: the global approach with Singleton pattern.

Comment: @ISTB Why not just have a look-up cache as member of your MainWindow class or `QApplication` subclass? That sounds like a good place to me.

Comment: I was just thinking what would be the best way in object oriented programming to organize the cose. And as long as I know, design patterns should help. In this particular case Singleton seems to be perfect, but I am not sure if there are better solutions. If I subclass the QApplication, I will have the same problem, but just in another place...

Comment: @ISTB Singletons are an anti-pattern. They usually turn out to be overused and to be a replacement for global variables.

Comment: Yes, I heard about it, but there il no alternative. If you need a place to keep your data, what would be the best solution? Singletons seem to offer an elegant solution

Comment: @ISTB As I said: Define a cache (a class, a typedef, whatever) and take it as a member of either your QMainWindow or your QApplication by extending them.